# Django Admin Models. Foreign Key Pop Up Window Full Screen

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates, django-admin

There is a foreign key in one of my models.
In the add model page, when I click on the + button next to foreign key a pop up window appears.
I want this window to be Full screen.